# error - unhandledRejection: Error: Not supported at Object.react-markdown

Tags: reactjs, markdown

Currently I'm using [react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) as my markdown component in my react project. Along with this I'm also using rehype-raw and remark-gfm. Whenever I run the project I get the following error:

[image]

The following is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "next-images": "^1.8.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-markdown": "^7.0.1",
    "rehype-raw": "^6.1.0",
    "remark-gfm": "^2.0.0",
  },
```

and my component:

```
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
import rehypeRaw from "rehype-raw";

export default function Home({ posts }) {
  return (
     <main className={styles.main}>
        {posts &&
          posts.map((image) => (
            <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
              <ReactMarkdown
                children={image.Content}
                rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
      </main>
   );
}
```

Error shown in logs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced similar error too, then I've found this solution:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/25454#issuecomment-903513941

ReactMarkdown is an ESM module which means it cannot be `required` but rather `imported`. If you are actually `importing` in your code, it can be, that the transpiler (e.g.: Babel) changes this, hence the error. So this can be a possible cause of the error.

What you can do to solve this (also described in the issue commit by others):

1. `npm i next-transpile-modules`
2. In `next.config.js` do the following:

```js
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['react-markdown']);

module.exports = withTM({
...restOfYourConfig
})
```

3. Import ReactMarkdown like this: `import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown/react-markdown.min';`

Other sources:

https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/import-esm-externals

https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules